# Eclipse Emulator is Slow

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After using xcode, I realzied how slow the android emulator on eclipse really is. Is it possible to speed it up in anyway? It is even slower in android studios.

Comment: The emulator can be as fast as your computer can run. One way you can do is to keep the emulator open and hot push the code change. But honestly, if this is a problem, use USB and test on real phone

Comment: Leave the emulator running. It's quite slow to start up I agree, but once running, it's fairly quick to re-deploy your app.

Comment: @IsabelHM Though it's technically true that the emulator is as fast as your pc, it still is slow even on high end machines. It's an _Emulator_ not a _Simulator_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow)

Comment: Buy a decent CPU (quad core, at least 2.600 GHz), and all will go really fast

Comment: @Gumbo That's exactly the reason why I recommend him to keep the emulator up and running to avoid the wait (which is what many others recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the SDK manager and install HAXM.
It won't be installed completely from there. 
In order to completely install it , go to the sdk folder/extras/intel and find HAXM and then install it from there.
my emulator takes some seconds.I have a mac.